# run multiple function call at once. but terminated all running function if one finished

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I have 5 function who I need to run it at once. But terminate all functions after one function finish. It is possible? I have searched but not find any answer related to my problem.

Comment: [`Promise.race`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race) might be solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Promise.race`.

---

Example with `Promise.race`

```js
function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}

function func() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const time = getRandomInt(1000, 3000);

    console.log(`Function terminate in ${time} ms`);

    setTimeout(() => resolve(), time);
  });
}

let time = Date.now();

(async() => {
  const time = Date.now();

  await Promise.race([
    func(),
    func(),
    func(),
  ]);

  console.log(`Over after ${Date.now() - time} ms`);
})();
```

---

Example with `Promise.all`

```js
function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}

function func() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const time = getRandomInt(1000, 3000);

    console.log(`Function terminate in ${time} ms`);

    setTimeout(() => resolve(), time);
  });
}

(async() => {
  let time = Date.now();

  await Promise.all([
    func(),
    func(),
    func(),
  ]);

  console.log(`Over after ${Date.now() - time} ms`);
})();
```